# Query the postgresql database records implementing some logic

Tags: postgresql

The table dividend consists of companies and their respective fiscal year of
dividend distribution. Some companies give dividends every year, but some companies do not. From an investment point of view, Those companies who have given dividends for at least 3 consecutive years in the past are labelled as 'valuestocks'. Please help me to write a query to find the 'valuestocks' i.e the companies that have given dividend for at least 3 consecutive year in the past.

This is how the table is created with the columns.

```
CREATE TABLE dividend
(
    company character varying(12),
    fiscal_year integer
)
```

If I have the following data inserted inside my table

```
company,fiscal_year
-------------------
AHPC,20702071
AHPC,20712072
AHPC,20732074
AHPC,20762077
CZBIL,20692070
CZBIL,20702071
CZBIL,20712072
CZBIL,20732074
GBIME,20692070
GBIME,20702071
GBIME,20712072
GBIME,20732074
```

Expected Output

```
valuestocks
------------
{"CZBIL ",""GBIME "}
```

I'm looking for a postgres SQL query for this problem. Can it be done in a single line of  SQL statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the recursion should help:

```sql
INSERT INTO dividend VALUES
 ('AHPC',20702071),
 ('AHPC',20712072),
 ('AHPC',20732074),
 ('AHPC',20762077),
 ('CZBIL',20692070),
 ('CZBIL',20702071),
 ('CZBIL',20712072),
 ('CZBIL',20732074),
 ('GBIME',20692070),
 ('GBIME',20702071),
 ('GBIME',20712072),
 ('GBIME',20732074);

WITH RECURSIVE pre1 AS (
  -- get the human readable year
  SELECT company, LEFT(fiscal_year::TEXT,4)::INT AS yr FROM dividend
), pre2 AS (
  -- all applicants for the start of the sequence
  SELECT pre1.company, pre1.yr, 1 AS cs 
   FROM pre1
  UNION DISTINCT
  -- append consecutives
  SELECT pre1.company, pre1.yr, pre2.cs + 1 
   FROM pre1
   JOIN pre2 
     ON pre1.company = pre2.company
    AND pre1.yr = pre2.yr + 1
)
-- aggregate results as json or array (while removing duplicates)
SELECT JSONB_AGG(DISTINCT company) FROM pre2
-- SELECT ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT company) FROM pre2
WHERE cs >= 3; -- at least 3 consecutives in any past
```

this seem to work as expected

Comment: For this data `LEFT(fiscal_year::TEXT,4)::INT` is equal to `fiscal_year/10000` BTW

Answer (score 2):

It appears your fiscal_year incorporates the 2 calendar years. To get 3 constitutive years you need to split them and then work with just 1; either the 1st 4 digits or the last 4 digits.  Either way you can use the LEAD (of lag) window function with the second parameter to specify the number of to look at, then compare the results +/- 1 or 2 as appropriate.

```
select distinct on (company) company
  from ( select company, fiscal_year 
              , lead( fiscal_year,1) over( partition by company order by fiscal_year) fym1
              , lead( fiscal_year,2) over( partition by company order by fiscal_year) fym2               
           from dividend
       ) csq
   where fiscal_year/10000 = fym1/10000 - 1 
     and fiscal_year/10000 = fym2/10000 - 2 
   order by company;
```